# Is there a better option than using an anchor tag '?name=' as a session variable?

Tags: php, html

This may be a wrong way to do it but I use anchor tags to display the name of a clicked button on another page.
For example:

`http://localhost/mod.php?name=Joe`

When I click a button with a value Joe, the next page will have Joe displayed as a heading. I use `$_REQUEST['name']` and store it in a session variable so that I can call it on other pages if needed. Now, the problem is if I'm accessing that page(with Joe as its heading) from other pages, I get an error because the `$_REQUEST['name']` does not exist on those other pages.

Is there a better way to display anchor tags on pages?

Comment: `if(isset($_REQUEST['name'])){....}else{...}`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. How do I use that to display headings on a page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['name'])!="") 
{
    echo $_REQUEST['name'];
} 
else 
{
    echo "Guest";
}
```

Comment: isset returns true\false you don't evaluate it against an empty string

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the name parameter, you can store it in a session variable. This way, you can get it from other pages where you don't pass the parameter.

However, consider to pass an identifier (an integer value), it's safer than pass directly the name.

Comment: For example, if I click on a button named Joe, I use `$_REQUEST['name']` to get the name then store it in, `$_SESSION["a"]`. This works when I call the session on other pages but when I click on a link that takes me back to the Joe page, I get an error and Joe doesn't display.

Comment: Just add name parameter to the link that takes you back to the Joe page, and/or in Joe page check if name parameter is sent, if not, just load session var (checking if isset before).